# Where does Firefox keep cookies?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, cookies

Where does Firefox store my cookies on a windows 7 home machine?
I have looked in AppData but don't see any cookie or cache folder.

Comment: look at profile folder. It's profile specific data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firefox generally stores cookies here:

`C:\Users\`*User name*`\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\some random list of characters.default`

An easier way to open this:
WIN+R (key combination), and then:
`%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Profiles\Firefox\Profiles\randomstring.default\`

(You can select the folders one by one in the run dialog. Just start typing the address.)

Comment: On Windows 8 my Firefox 19.0 cookies.sqlite* and cookies.txt files are in AppData\Roaming\..., not AppData\Local\...

Answer (score 2):

The cookies are in the folder mentioned by Corporate Geek (%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Profiles\Firefox\Profiles\randomstring.default), in the file **cookies.sqlite**.

To manage individual cookies you have to open Firefox and go to **"Settings\Privacy\remove individual cookies"**

Answer (score 2):

A cookie is information stored on your computer by a website you visit.

In some browsers, each cookie is a small file but in Firefox, all cookies are stored in a single file, located in the Firefox profile folder.

Cookies often store your settings for a website, such as your preferred language or location. When you return to the site, Firefox sends back the cookies that belong to the site. This allows the site to present you with information customized to fit your needs.

At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button, go over to the Help menu (on Windows XP, click on the Help menu) and select Troubleshooting Information. The Troubleshooting Information tab will open.
Under the Application Basics section, click on Show Folder. A window with your profile files will open.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, these are all correct answers, but involve a lot of work for something that needs done often. What I did is this:

1. Do a MANUAL cleanup of your cookies, making sure you leave alone the ones you need to access sites you want, such as banks, amazon whatever. Close Firefox.
2. Make a copy of the cookies.sqllite file (find it as described above).
3. Save copy somewhere you can find it easily.
4. Next time you want to clean up cookies (I do it often) just go and click on "Remove All Cookies"
5. Copy the "clean" cookies.sqlite file to overwrite the active one.
6. Open Firefox. You now have cleaned all undesirable cookies and STILL have the ones needed. You can also create a batch file to do this in a click.
   Works fine for me.

Comment: This is a great answer, but the question just asked where they are located.  You might want to ask a new question (What is an efficient way to clear unwanted cookies in Firefox), and post this answer there, instead (you are allowed to answer your own question).  People are unlikely to find your answer here if they are searching on this question.  BTW, why do you need step 4?

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to `about:support` in Firefox
2. Seach `Profile Folder`
3. Click on `Open Folder` or copy folder value

For those who don't find `cookies.sqlite` in the folders from the answers above.