# If I move my hard drive to another computer, will I be logged out of my e-mail?

Tags: hard-drive, email

I’m using Windows 8 (x86) and I’m trying to regain access to an e-mail account I haven't used in a while, and I found out that the browser on my old laptop keeps me logged in, so while I don't have a password, I could archive my messages. However, this old laptop is pretty much broken and keeps shutting down after 10 minutes.

So, if I take the hard drive out and put in another machine, will the browser still open the mail account when running in, or will cookies etc. be somehow reset?

For background, I set an OpenMailBox account as a recovery e-mail; back then it worked, now automatic messages from Yahoo! don’t seem appear.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question in order to let others know if you are using a Microsoft OS or an Apple OS. It might help getting an answer more suited to you. :)

Comment: What kind of email account is this? Do you have the ability to reset your own password? This is what’s confusing to me, since while you might have forgotten the password to the account, why can’t you just initiate a password reset on a new machine?

Comment: @JakeGould I can't reset password because I set a openmailbox account as a recovery e-mail - back then it worked, now automatic messages from Yahoo don't appear.
(using opmbx for anything was a mistake - now I would know better :/)

Comment: Hmmm… Are you 100% sure you can’t contact OpenMailBox and ask them to investigate? The reality is there is no reason Yahoo! automatically generated emails should just disappear like that. They should at least be flagged as possible SPAM or something like that.

Comment: @JakeGould I've written to Support yesterday, no answer yet since it's weekend (I guess). OpenMailBox had a lot of problems since changing the owner some time ago and I'd rather not depend on their willingness to help.

Comment: What browser? (and yes, this should work, but there are likely easier ways - like copying the profile)

Comment: @davidgo Mozilla Firefox.
Do you mean copying Windows profile, or something else?

Comment: Mozilla has a "profile" which has most of the information the browser stores.  It is highly likely that you can simply backup the profile and copy it to your new computer to retain the old functionality - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles   - Also see https://superuser.com/questions/387372/where-does-firefox-keep-cookies